# Can I configure nginx with proxy_pass to use an error document on the proxied server?

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, proxy, http-status-code-404, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've configured nginx with `proxy_pass` to proxy URLs like `/uploads/foo.png` to fetch from an S3 bucket, but obviously missing files result in ugly XML errors, and I want to return a static HTML file.

I tried using the "static website" feature of S3, but it always returns (incorrect) 403 status codes with the error doc, and it seems there's no way to alter that via `proxy_pass`.

For various reasons, using a local file on the nginx server isn't an option. This nginx instance *only* does proxying.

Can I have nginx re-request an error document from the proxied S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. First place 404.html in your S3 bucket. Then configure your location block like this:

```
location /uploads {
  proxy_pass YOUR_S3_BUCKET_URL;

  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  error_page 403 404 /uploads/404.html;
}
```

`proxy_intercept_errors` will tell nginx to handle error codes in the proxied response.

The `error_page` will handle the S3 error code by internally changing the request to `/uploads/404.html`

And finally your existing `location /uploads` block will fetch that 404 doc from the proxied server!

Presumably you could even fetch the error doc from a different origin:

```
location /uploads {
  proxy_pass ORIGIN_A_URL;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  error_page 403 404 /error-docs/404.html;
}

location /error-docs {
  proxy_pass ORIGIN_B_URL;
}
```